# AWS iot ResourceNotFound Exception android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

```
AWSIotClient client = new AWSIotClient(sAWSCredentials);

ListThingsRequest thingList = new ListThingsRequest();

client.listThings(thingList);
```

Here am getting

> com.amazonaws.services.iot.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found (Service: AWSIot; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 2c969242-3d0e-5e2f-58df-f7e24bf48b5a)

Comment: that means ur credentials do not match to AwsIot

Comment: Credentials correct, because am able to get thingShadow details.When it comes to access ThingsList am getting this exception.

Comment: check for any name typos, and there sometimes is an auth issue when level rights are not assigned. I.e the credentials might not have access to the api, where u get to list all device. Have not been in touch with the new AWSIOT versions since long time. but it use to be there

Comment: This is the credentials passing to AWSIotClient.             BasicAWSCredentials sAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_KEY); I am not understanding what would be problem

Comment: The thing is u need Oauth2.0 token request for such commands. that is all i know. find out more regarding it. i do not know more, happy to help with what i couuld

Comment: You can try setting your region to correct region like `us-east-1` before making the requests.

Comment: Is your AWS-IoT endpoint correct with the correct region? Also, check if you have attached the appropriate policies